# Proving if $I$ nilpotent and $I\neq N(R)$ then $R/I$ has nilpotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, nilpotence

I am trying to prove that if $R$ is a ring and $I$ is a nilpotent ideal of $R$ and $I\neq N(R)$ then $R/I$ has a nonzero nilpotent element.

**My attempt**

Since $I$ nilpotent ideal of $R$ we have $I \subset N(R)$. So if $I\neq N(R)$ then $I$ is a strict subset of $N(R)$. So there is an $x \in N(R) \setminus I $.

Therefore $x+ I \in R/I $ and $x+ I \neq 0$. Since $x \in N(R)$, $x$ is nilpotent so there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^n =0 $. So $(x+I)^n=x^n+I = 0 $ and so $x+I$ is a nonzero nilpotent element of $R/I$.

Is this proof ok?

Comment: Your definition if nilpotent ideal seems incorrect. An ideal $I$ is nilpotent is there exists some $k\geq 1$ such that $I^k=0$ (or equivalently such that the product of $k$ elements of $I$ is $0$). Your definition is the definition of nil ideal (an ideal for which every element is nilpotent).

Comment: Anyway, this does not matter much.  Your proof is correct, since a nilpotent ideal is a nil ideal (if $I^k=0$, then for all $x\in I, x^k\in I^k$, so $x^k=0$.

Comment: I’m using the fact that a nilpotent ideal is necessarily a nil ideal.